# customize td inner html in mvccontrib grid

Tags: url, grid, mvccontrib, html-table

I wonder if there way to customize td inner HTML of grid, for example I need to bound some field, and make clickable.
 Didn't found any other way, except adding onclick attribute.
    Columns(column => column.For(x => x.GotToPursue).Attributes(@onclick => "align-right")
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to this I've found is to write your on extension method, working with already formed innerhtml to change it.